# PHP: sorting a multidimentional array ($arr[$i]['v'])

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

i have array in type of (UNSORTED VERSION):

```
<?php
$arr['foo']['man']      = 5 ;
$arr['foo']['str']      = 'string5' ;
$arr['foobar']['man']   = 2 ;
$arr['foobar']['str']   = 'string2' ;
$arr['barfoo']['man']   = 4 ;
$arr['barfoo']['str']   = 'string4' ;
$arr['foofoo']['man']   = 1 ;
$arr['foofoo']['str']   = 'string1' ;
$arr['bar']['man']      = 3 ;
$arr['bar']['str']      = 'string3' ;
?>
```

i want to sort it in decending order while preserving all other data in that array, i.e.

```
<?php
$arr['foo']['man']      = 5 ;
$arr['foo']['str']      = 'string5' ;
$arr['barfoo']['man']   = 4 ;
$arr['barfoo']['str']   = 'string4' ;
$arr['bar']['man']      = 3 ;
$arr['bar']['str']      = 'string3' ;
$arr['foobar']['man']   = 2 ;
$arr['foobar']['str']   = 'string2' ;
$arr['foofoo']['man']   = 1 ;
$arr['foofoo']['str']   = 'string1' ;
?>
```

i have looked at many sorting functions in PHP but havent found any solutions

can anybody help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of an initial unsorted version of the array to compare against?

Comment: hey ryven, sorry, it was some stackoverflow editor bug, forgot to put one line break between code and scentence, its there now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function:

```
uasort($yourArray, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['man'], $b['man']);
});
```

Or look at [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array-multisort)