# PHP: multidimentional array sorting in type of $array[$i]['v'];$array[$i]['c'] , while preserving the order

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: sorting a multidimentional array ($arr[$i]['v'])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592663/php-sorting-a-multidimentional-array-arriv)

I have an array of UNSORTED VERSION type.

```
$arr['foo']['man']      = 5;
$arr['foo']['str']      = 'string5';
$arr['foobar']['man']   = 2;
$arr['foobar']['str']   = 'string2';
$arr['barfoo']['man']   = 4;
$arr['barfoo']['str']   = 'string4';
$arr['foofoo']['man']   = 1;
$arr['foofoo']['str']   = 'string1';
$arr['bar']['man']      = 3;
$arr['bar']['str']      = 'string3';
```

I want to sort it in decending order while preserving all other data in that array, i.e.

```
$arr['foo']['man']      = 5;
$arr['foo']['str']      = 'string5';
$arr['barfoo']['man']   = 4;
$arr['barfoo']['str']   = 'string4';
$arr['bar']['man']      = 3;
$arr['bar']['str']      = 'string3';
$arr['foobar']['man']   = 2;
$arr['foobar']['str']   = 'string2';
$arr['foofoo']['man']   = 1;
$arr['foofoo']['str']   = 'string1';
```

I have looked at many sorting functions in PHP but havent found any solutions.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post the same question twice. You already had an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort) and pass a custom comparison callable:

```
function compareItems($a, $b) {
    return $b['man'] - $a['man'];
}

uasort($arr, 'compareItems');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uasort($arr, function($l, $r){
    return $r['man'] - $l['man'];
})
```